# Android - google maps v2 - How to clear map makers without blink

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I should use WeakReference to maintain the markers and set visibility when I want to hide/show markers, right?

What if the marker references are cleared... then the weak reference dont have the markers objects, but are still in the map... how can clear the map without blink (`map.clear()`)?